# Can make z-index work as it should even dough they are position absolute

Tags: html, css, z-index

So I have 2 elements, the doted circles that should be z-index: -999; so they are 100% in the background and the second element a login form that should be z-index 999. But even dough they are position absolute the z-index doesn't seem to take effect. Since I'm using flask I tried joining the files instead of having flask load the circles.html to the login.html but still doesn't work.

Image with the problem:
[image]

The Login CSS:

```
.login-div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 999 !important;
}
```

Circles CSS:
.circles in the div that has inside the img with the circles.

```
.circles{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: -999 !important;
}
```

I only have these two divs with z-index so I believe its not a stacking problem but let me know what you think.

Comment: can you share the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the background color to white and it worked, so it wasn't a z-index problem.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you want

Solution 1:

```css
.circles{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: -1;
}

.login-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: white;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="login-div">
  <h1>Log In</h1>
</div>
<div class="circles">
  <img src="https://glowvarietyshow.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/placeholder-image.jpg" alt="Image Test">
</div>
```

this `z-index: -1;` makes the element behind the other elements.

Solution 2:

```css
.background--page {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
}

.login-div {
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background--page" style="background-image: url('https://glowvarietyshow.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/placeholder-image.jpg')">
  <div class="login-div">
    <h1>Log In</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Through `background-image`, you won't have to work with the `z-index`.

Comment: With the second solution, something strange happened where the login-div was still under the background image.

Comment: Cuz as you can see in the image the circles are under everything but the login-div (the white box that holds the form)

Comment: I was messing around in the styling inside the browser and with no intention, I clicked in the set background color and it worked. I'm so dumb. Sorry for wasting your time guys.

Comment: np, I'm glad I helped.